# Change of, in or to

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

I would like to ask for the difference in usage between 'change of, 'change in' and 'change to'

For example, which of the three is the correct form/most used?

- I had a change of address
- I had a change in address
- I had a change to my address (sounds awkward)

I want to find out the best phrase use to indicate formally that I moved house.
'I changed my address' is confusing as it sounds like what I would say after updating information on a website.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are talking of something you did/requested, _I changed my address_ is probably your best choice; _I had a change_ is about a change that you didn't do, or requested (e.g. some authority changed your residence address that results in an official document).

Comment: So if I say, the country had a change of government, it would mean  that the change isn't something I requested ? What about I had a change of opinion, how does it differ from I changed my opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You should say *I had a change of address*, in the same way you say *a change of air*, *a change of heart*, *a change of opinion*, or *a change of government*.

You would probably say *I changed my address*, except in the case you are talking of something you didn't request/initialize/do, for example when talking about a change done by an authority on some official document.